# What electronic component does RT1 refer to in the following diagram?

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I am developing a PCB for the following schematic design. I cannot figure out what the label RT1 refers to ?
Please refer the following image.

[image]

Comment: The accompanying text should tell you. If there's a calibration procedure that says "adjust RT1" for example, it may be a trimmer (variable resistor) Or it may be a thermistor, Or something else.

Comment: Do you know what this circuit should do? My first guess was also thermistor.

Comment: U1B has a gain ranging from 360 to 850 regulated by temperature extremes on RT1

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 It is a thermistor, but how to decide whether to use NTC or PTC? The circuit is the breakout for a gas sensor. This circuit is required to detect gas concentrations.

Comment: how? by experience ...if you decide  you need more gain (R) at lower temperatures, then NTC. (also) This schematic is unconventional to show V- above V+ for an Op Amp and to have cap symbol touch the lines. Whoever did this needs to learn drawing standards by reading good examples used anywhere around the world.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Got it. still building my electronics experience. The design is given by the chinese company manufacturing the sensors.

Comment: Chinese often do this to obfuscate a direct copy of someone else's design, but still,inexperienced, probably an EU design.

Answer (score 2):

RT is a [reference designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_designator)(wikipedia article, with list) for [thermistors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor).

Unfortunately there are basically no other details in that shcematic about the component, so it's impossible to tell if it's a NTC or PTC type, let alone the other details (k, β, a, b, c, tolerance etc.).

Answer (score 0):

It's a [thermistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor) and its initial (at room teperature) resistance is 10k. But I cannot determine whether it's a NTC or a PTC.

Comment: I believe it is 10k0 at 25C